# Секрет адаптивной верстки

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Специально нашел видимый пример:
У нас есть 2 сайта:

1. https://gudostudio.tk/
2. https://gudostudio.tk/gudo

На первом, при маленьком разрешении экрана, всё нормально. На втором, при уменьшении экрана, вся верстка тоже уменьшается.
Я специально открыл эти 2 сайта ещё и на телефоне, и, в итоге, на втором сайте ничего не понятно, слишком мелко.
Собственно вопрос: почему на втором сайте уменьшается размер элементов, а на первом нет. И как это исправить (примерно)?

P.S. Cайты не мои, у меня просто такая же проблема возникла, и я наткнулся на этот сайт

Comment: необходимо добавить в head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки даже не открывал, но могу предположить что проблема в отсутствии

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```